# Lubuntu installation on Dell Inspiron 6400 - no wifi networks

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, dell

Hi any help appreciated.  I have just installed Lubuntu on my old Dell Inspiron 6400.

Can't see any reference to wireless networking, or any networks to connect to.

I've tried to see if the wireless card needs switching on (it worked fine with Windows XP) by using Fn + F2 but that doesn't appear to do anything.

I've installed Lubuntu alongside Windows XP, and if I reboot to XP the Wireless connection works automatically.

Help!

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Welcome to askubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect to the internet using a modem or cable then use the command `sudo modprobe b43` and see the outcome.

If it doesn't work, open the terminal `(ctrl+alt+t)`. Then type:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Then restart yout computer. (The changes only take place when you restart.)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks I can try your suggestion - will this impact the ability of the wifi connection to work in Windows?

Comment: This assumes he has a Broadcom wireless device. How do you know he does?

Comment: @chili555 I think `Dell Inspiron 6400`  has a broadcom wireless device

Comment: @Kris no this won't impact the wifi connection on Windows at all

Comment: My wireless device is a Dell 1390 wlan mini card

Comment: @Kris then the solution I gave to you should work

Comment: @AimadMajdou Trust but verify.

Comment: That's brilliant thank you Aimad.  Now to explore Lubuntu!

Comment: @Kris your welcome Kris please mark my answer as the solution if that helped you

Comment: Marked as having answered my question - thank you Aimad!